# animate display property in css

Tags: html, css

I can't explain my problem without an example. So, here is the example:

### HTML:

```
<p>H<span>yper </span>T<span>ext </span>M<span>arkup </span>L<span>anguage</span></p>
```

### CSS:

```
p {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif;
    font-size: 72px;
}

span {
    display: none;
}

p:hover span{
    display: inline;
}
```

### OUTPUT:

We will see `HTML` written on the screen.

When I hover my mouse pointer on the text, it will show full text:

```
Hyper Text Markup Language
```

### What I want:

I want current behaviour to be same, but I want to use animation so that this thing shows up slowly

### What I have tried

I tried to animate `display` property, but It's not animatable.

So, I tried the other way round.

I tried to use `visibility: Hidden;` and `opacity: 0;`. But in both cases the hidden element takes up the space. So, the output will be something like:

```
H     T    M      L
```

### JS Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/Vishal1419/twzok58d/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do that without script is to use `max-width`, where one set it to a value big enough to accommodate the longest text

To make this wrap properly, I also added a second span and a pseudo element.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/twzok58d/2/)

Stack snippet

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 72px;
}
p > span {
  display: inline-block;
}
p span span {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-width 1s;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
p span span::after {
  content: '\00a0'
}
p:hover span span {
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<p><span>H<span>yper</span></span><span>T<span>ext</span></span><span>M<span>arkup</span></span><span>L<span>anguage</span></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve that with CSS3, animations are only for numeric properties such as size, position, or color.

But you can use jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut functions to make what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can achive that using CSS3 and transition doesnt animate the display attribute. Try using jQuery.

You can:

```
$('p').hover(function () {
  $('span').fadeIn();
}, function () {
    $('span').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Nope, I already tried that. The hidden spans takes up the space.

Comment: Yep I actually noticed that. I dont think you can achieve that with CSS3.. As the the display doesnt animate. You can do it tought with  Jquery. I will Edit my question.

Comment: Why are you using unnecessary vendor prefixes>

Comment: Not sure if you want to avoid Jquery but I think you can only achive it that way. Both opacity and visibility will always take up the space and css3 doesnt animate display's.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes without an explanation.